# How can I count times solely from one column in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

Currently I have this query below which produces awesome results, however, I'm trying to get a count of the total SiteIDs (regardless of other factors within the query).

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
    TotalCharts ,
    SiteID ,
    Type,
    CASE
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN '1-4 Charts'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '5-9 Charts'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 10 AND 24 THEN '10-24 Charts'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN '25-49 Charts'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 50 AND 99 THEN '50-99 Charts'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 100 AND 249 THEN '100-249 Charts'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 250 AND 499 THEN '250-499 Charts'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN '500-1000 Charts'  
        WHEN TotalCharts > 1000 THEN 'Greater 1000'
    END AssignmentType,
    CASE
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN '1'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '2'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 10 AND 24 THEN '3'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN '4'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 50 AND 99 THEN '5'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 100 AND 249 THEN '6'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 250 AND 499 THEN '7'  
        WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN '8'  
        WHEN TotalCharts > 1000 THEN '9'
    END AssignmentTypeIndex
FROM (
    SELECT
    COUNT(c.ChartID) TotalCharts,
    c.SiteID, 
    CASE WHEN ChartRetrievalMethodID IS NULL THEN wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
ELSE ChartRetrievalMethodID END as Type
FROM
    dbo.Sites s 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Charts c ON s.SiteID = c.SiteID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.ChartRetrievalInformation cri ON c.ChartID=cri.ChartID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.WFSiteEvents wfse ON s.SiteID = wfse.SiteID AND EventStatusID IN (1,2)
    LEFT JOIN dbo.WFSiteEventTypes wfset ON wfse.EventTypeID = wfset.EventTypeID
    LEFT JOIN dbo.WFSiteEventGroups wfseg ON wfset.SiteEventGroupID = wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
WHERE
    c.SiteID <> 110
    and s.ProjectID=160
GROUP BY
    c.SiteID, 
    CASE WHEN ChartRetrievalMethodID IS NULL THEN wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
ELSE ChartRetrievalMethodID END
) d
ORDER BY SiteID
```

So Right now it's displaying individual siteIDs and I would like to display a full count of SiteIds

However, the tricky part here that I count really use `count(distinct siteID)` is because there are lines with various info for the same SiteID.  Example:

```
TotalCharts | SiteID | SiteEventGroupID | AssignmentType | AssignmentTypeIndex
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9           | 12345  | 4                | 5-9 Charts     | 2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           | 12345  | 3                | 1-4 Charts     | 1
```

So in this case I have two distinct rows for the same SiteID, and I just want to count this particular SiteIDs regardless of the other info.  So instead of counting this SiteID twice, I'd like it to only count once.

Is there a way that I can just count that particular column?

Answer (score 1):

What you need in this case is a window function.
Here's a reference for TSQL window functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms189461.aspx

Modifying your existing code block:

```
SELECT
    TotalCharts,
    SiteID,
    Type, 
    AssignmentType,
    AssignmentTypeIndex,
    COUNT(SiteID) OVER (PARTITION BY SiteID) NumRowsbySite
FROM(
    SELECT 
        TotalCharts ,
        SiteID,     
        Type,
        CASE
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN '1-4 Charts'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '5-9 Charts'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 10 AND 24 THEN '10-24 Charts'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN '25-49 Charts'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 50 AND 99 THEN '50-99 Charts'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 100 AND 249 THEN '100-249 Charts'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 250 AND 499 THEN '250-499 Charts'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN '500-1000 Charts'  
            WHEN TotalCharts > 1000 THEN 'Greater 1000'
        END AssignmentType,
        CASE
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 1 AND 4 THEN '1'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 5 AND 9 THEN '2'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 10 AND 24 THEN '3'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 25 AND 49 THEN '4'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 50 AND 99 THEN '5'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 100 AND 249 THEN '6'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 250 AND 499 THEN '7'  
            WHEN TotalCharts BETWEEN 500 AND 1000 THEN '8'  
            WHEN TotalCharts > 1000 THEN '9'
        END AssignmentTypeIndex
    FROM (
        SELECT
        COUNT(c.ChartID) TotalCharts,
        c.SiteID, 
        CASE WHEN ChartRetrievalMethodID IS NULL THEN wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
    ELSE ChartRetrievalMethodID END as Type
    FROM
        dbo.Sites s 
        INNER JOIN dbo.Charts c ON s.SiteID = c.SiteID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.ChartRetrievalInformation cri ON c.ChartID=cri.ChartID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.WFSiteEvents wfse ON s.SiteID = wfse.SiteID AND EventStatusID IN (1,2)
        LEFT JOIN dbo.WFSiteEventTypes wfset ON wfse.EventTypeID = wfset.EventTypeID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.WFSiteEventGroups wfseg ON wfset.SiteEventGroupID = wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
    WHERE
        c.SiteID <> 110
        and s.ProjectID=160
    GROUP BY
        c.SiteID, 
        CASE WHEN ChartRetrievalMethodID IS NULL THEN wfseg.SiteEventGroupID
    ELSE ChartRetrievalMethodID END
    ) d
    ORDER BY SiteID) a
```